# Remove empty lines from string, but allow one empty between every line

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove excessive empty lines from a string, but allow one empty line between every line. Like:

```
line1





line2
```

Should become:

```
line1

line2
```

I did find the following regex (forgot where i found it):

```
preg_replace('/^\n+|^[\t\s]*\n+/m','',$message);
```

This works, but removes all empty lines without leaving an empty line between every line.

Edit: I just created a quick example at http://jsfiddle.net/RAqSS/

Comment: Did you mean: "Should become: line1 \n \n line2"?

Comment: Basically if there are more than 2 empty lines between every line, it should be trimmed down to just one. So basically that remaining empty line should be as high as 1 em.

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by 'empty line'. What you describe in the question isn't an empty line.

Comment: I just added a quick example at http://jsfiddle.net/RAqSS/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
\n(\s*\n){2,}
```

with:

```
\n\n
```

Like this:

```
preg_replace('/\n(\s*\n){2,}/', "\n\n", $message); // Quotes are important here.
```

If you don't want an empty line, you would change the `{2,}` to a `+` and use a single `\n`. It would actually work with a `+` instead of `{2,}`. The `{2,}` is an optimization.

Comment: This one works precisely! If you don't want empty line, you would use the following code: `preg_replace('/\n(\s*\n)+/', "\n", $output);`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
preg_replace('/\n(\s*\n)+/', "\n\n", $message);
```

This will replace a newline followed by any number of blank lines with a single newline.

Comment: That doesn't work. It somehow removes all content, leaving an empty string.

Comment: `'\n'` is not a single newline.

Comment: @KendallFrey - Thanks, originally OP was asking for `line\nline2` but it looks like you were interpreting it correctly based on the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Sempiterna - I just noticed that I had forgotten the trailing `/` on the regex, that may have caused the problem.  Glad you were able to find a working solution!

Comment: By the way, see mine and AshleyS's answers for the correct way to put a newline in string.

Comment: And now it becomes an almost exact duplicate of mine :) Have a +1.

Comment: @KendallFrey - Thanks :) Python is my primary language and single/double quotes are the same there, so I sometimes get tripped up when assuming the same thing about other languages.

Comment: I thought \n was a single empty newline, but indeed it is \n\n. Thanks everyone for providing answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your jsFiddle, try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\n(\n*\s)+/', "\n\n", $message);
```

Comment: Your second code almost works. It replaces all empty lines and replaces them with an empty line between each piece of text. But it also adds an empty line between each piece of text that did not have multiple empty lines.

Comment: Can you update your question with a more detailed example of your data and expected results?